# Check if checkbox or radio button inside div is seleted

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery I want to check if checkboxes or radio button inside a div tag is selected and get the value of selected checkbox and radio buttons.

For Example:

```
     <div>
        Question
        <div>
            What is your name?
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="r1" checked/>abc<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="r1"/>pqr<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="r1"/>lmn<br/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="visibility: hidden">
        Question
        <div>
            What is your company name?
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="c1" checked/>comp1<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="c1"/>Comp2<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="c1"/>Comp3<br/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

on button click I want to show question and in front of that the answer of that question. Like as follows

What is your name =   abc

What is your company name = comp1, comp2

Thanks.

Comment: Did you come up with anything yourself so far?

Comment: I am able to get question but confused in getting answer values from radio or checkboxes..

Comment: Your `<input/>` elements have no real `value`, so it will be hard to get the `values` of the radioelements. First you have to change your `HTML` structure...

Comment: So "behind that", not "in front of that"

Comment: @Sandy: Interesting that you specify that you understand your own question. Is this homework?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I mean to say that I am getting question string from div tag but not answers options value. But never mind I have solved it on my own. Did not understand what you want to say by homework?

Comment: @Sandy: Oh, oops, never mind :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/ on how to use the :checked selector.

Answer (score 8):

Here you go dude some code sample

```
 var chk = $('#dvTest input:radio:checked');
 chk.attr('value');
```

It will give you which radio buttton is checked. Whaever value you want keep that in that value property for ex:

```
 <input type="radio" name="r1" checked="checked" value="abc"/>
```

Same you can do for checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/magicaj/xFqHN/

HTML:

```
<div>
    Question
    <div>
        What is your name? <span id="your-name"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="r1" value="abc" checked="checked" />abc<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="r1" value="pqr" />pqr<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="r1" value="lmn" />lmn<br/>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="comp" style="visibility: hidden">
    Question
    <div>
        What is your company name?<span id="comp-name"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="c1" value="comp1" checked/>comp1<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="c1" value="Comp2" />Comp2<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="c1" value="Comp3" />Comp3<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("input[name='r1']").click(function() {
    $("#your-name").html($(this).val());
    updateCompName();
    $("#comp").css("visibility", "visible");    
});

var updateCompName = function() {
    var element = $("#comp-name");
    var compNames = "";
    compCheckboxes.each(function() {
        if (this.checked === true) {
            compNames += " " + $(this).val();
        }
    });
    $("#comp-name").html(compNames);
}

var compCheckboxes = $("input[name='c1']");

compCheckboxes.click(updateCompName);
```

You were missing the `value` attribute on your radios and checkboxes.  I added spans placeholders to update the text with the current value of the radio/checkboxes.